# UDP vs TCP performance on a Python/Django application

Tags: python, tcp, redis, udp, synchronous

Say you have to push some statistic to some final TCP (HTTP) server on the cloud, which would be the most optimal implementation option regarding TIME:

1. having a local server running UDP acting as a buffer flushing data to the final HTTP server in a way your python code runs synchronously - just doing that UDP connection to push the information
2. using something like django_rq and have workers flushing the redis (also a local server) queue to the final HTTP cloud server

Is it possible to ensure one of the two options is going to be faster than the other? Is this something I should worry about or it's more likely to be negligible?

Comment: Do you have performance problems with the one or other option?

Comment: I currently have the option 1 in production but considering to move to 2.

Comment: Can you tolerate data loss?

Comment: Ideally not, but that's how it is right now so lets say I can